# How to echo multidimentional array posted from php

Tags: php

I have 2 php files.
1st php:

```
 //store values:
    $Hitcount=0;
    $result=array();
    while statement {
    $col = 0;
    $result[$Hitcount][$col]=$hit_name;
    $result[$Hitcount][++$col]=$hit_link;
    $Hitcount++;
    }
    //check stored values
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) 
    {
      foreach ($value as $k => $v) 
       {
            echo '$v'; echo",";
       }
    }
```

I got the following from the previous echo:

```
gi|1786181|gb|AE000111|ECAE000111,http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/1786181?report=genbank,
gi|1786250|gb|AE000117|ECAE000117,http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/1786250?report=genbank,
gi|1786240|gb|AE000116|ECAE000116,http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/1786240?report=genbank, gi|1786217|gb|AE000114|ECAE000114,http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/1786217?report=genbank,
```

Now, I want to post $result array to another php file.
To post,  1st php contains:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) 
                {
                    foreach ($value as $k => $v) 
                    {
                        echo "<input type='hidden' name='result[$k]' value='$v'/>";
                    }
                }
```

To receive $result array, 2nd php:

```
$result = empty($_POST['result']) ? array() : $_POST['result'];
foreach ($result as $key => $value ) 
                {
                    foreach ($value as $k => $v) 
                    {
                        echo $v;
                    }
                }
```

But, the echo give me:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach().
```

It mean the second foreach()statement.

Any help please?

**Edit 1:**
It is working now by fix 1st php as:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) 
{
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) 
    {
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='result[$key][$k]' value='$v'/>";
                                               ^^^^^^ add second key here
    }
}
```

Now, How can I save $result in the database? I want to:

```
insert row1 in the database and put $result[0][0] in col1 and put $result[0][1] in col2
insert row2 in the database and put $result[1][0] in col1 and put $result[1][1] in col2
insert row3 in the database and put $result[2][0] in col1 and put $result[2][1] in col2
and so on.
```

Now I try:

```
 foreach ($result as $key => $value) 
                {
                    foreach ($value as $k => $v) 
                    {
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO BlastResultFact (Hit) VALUES ('$v')";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
        if( $stmt === false ) {
             die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                    }
                }}

it insert row1 in the database and put $result[0][0] in col1 and
insert row2 in the database and put $result[0][1] in col1 and 
insert row3 in the database and put $result[1][0] in col1 and so on.
```

I believe I must include col2 (HitLink) in the insert tatement but what about $v?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO BlastResultFact (Hit, HitLink) VALUES ('$v')";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `input` tags are 1 dimensional, so your inner `foreach` will fail because each element of `$_POST['result']` is a string, not an array

```
$result = empty($_POST['result']) ? array() : $_POST['result'];
foreach ($result as $key => $value ) 
{
    // $value is a string!
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) 
    {
        echo $v;
    }
}
```

To correct the issue, modify your `input` tags to generate a 2d array:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) 
{
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) 
    {
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='result[$key][$k]' value='$v'/>";
                                               ^^^^^^ add second key here
    }
}
```

Now you should get a 2d array in `$_POST['result']` and be able to iterate the array with your original nested loop

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working now. Could you please read edit 1 in my post?

Comment: @Alaa the queries look ok to me, but I notice you only have 1 foreach and not 2, so if `result` is 2 dimensional `$hit_name` will be an array. If you need more help I recommend opening a new question with your table schema and sample data

Answer (score 1):

The array you are getting from `$_POST['result']` is a string not an array.
You need to `explode()` the string like this:

```
$result = empty($_POST['result']) ? array() : explode ( '|' ,$_POST['result']);
```

Comment: I did not have ',' in $result array!

Comment: I'm sorry, now i see you are using "|" instead or ","

Answer (score 0):

You Can POst using this Method.

```
foreach($array as $index=>$val) 
{
    //suppose you have three field
    $itemid=$_POST['item'][$index]['value'];
    $quantity=$_POST['quantity'][$index]['value'];
    $price=$_POST['unitprice'][$index]['value'];
}
```

Comment: I did not get it! I have 2 dim array whith unknown number of rows. sometimes 4 rows sometimes 2 sometimes n. but each row contains 2 indexes.